# Trying to override MultiValueContainer in react-select, but it is not receiving the Option data

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm attempting to override the MultiValueContainer so that I can optionally show an icon next to the MultiValueLabel. I tried this already with the MultiValueLabel Component, but the docs suggest that it does not receive the option value, but the MultiValueContainer does.

```
<CreatableSelect
   components={MultiValueContainer: CustomMultiValueContainer}
...

const CustomMultiValueContainer = (props) => {
    return (
        <components.MultiValueContainer {...props}>
            { props.option.showIcon &&
              <i class="user-icon" >
            }
            {props.children}
        </components.MultiValueContainer>
    )
}
```

When I do this, the only thing in props is the two children (the MultiValueLabel and MultiValueRemove). How do I get access to the option data here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to use the stable release version of react-select v2. Beta-6 had broken the functionality. MultiValueContainer/MultiValueLabel now receive the underlying option data as expected.